# Webpage config file

Tags: javascript, php, html, configuration, web-config

I need something like a configuration.properties file for my webpage. Like in php, js or just a txt file. I want to use it to change data afterwards, to make maintenance a little bit easier. But my i have no service or any think else running on my page so i need something different.

Is there anything, does anybody have any idea or hints to solve my problem? Or how to include it into my html files.

I was think about something like:

```
value = key
```

or

```
value = "key"
```

thanks for any help :)

Comment: What language? Or are you meaning configuration for a site of static HTML pages?

Comment: in html u cannot put dynamic data.but using ajax you can get what ever data u want from a php page and show it in html page

Comment: yeah. i need it for a static html page.

Comment: What language you are using in your project?

Comment: Currently html pages with javascript/JQuery and php. I would have no problem with something new to fix my problem.